# Having difficulty using an ASP.NET MVC ViewBag and DropDownListfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My difficulty is how to use `ViewBag` with `DropdownListFor`?

In my controller I am having:

```
TestModel model = new TestModel();
ViewBag.Clients = model.Clients;
ViewBag.StatusList = model.StatusList;
ViewBag.enumStatus = model.enumStatus;
ViewBag.intClient = model.intClient;
```

In my TestModel

```
public SelectList Clients { get; set; }       
public SelectList StatusList { get; set; }
public ActiveStatus enumStatus { get; set; }
public int? intClient { get; set; }
```

In my View

I want to use `DropDownListFor` to display the ViewBag values, how can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

You could do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.intClient, ViewBag.Clients)
```

But I would recommend you to avoid ViewBag/ViewData and profit from your view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new TestModel();
    model.Clients = new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new { Value = "1", Text = "client 1" },
        new { Value = "2", Text = "client 2" },
        new { Value = "3", Text = "client 3" },
    }, "Value", "Text");
    model.intClient = 2;
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.intClient, Model.Clients)
```

Comment: I cant use  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.intClient, ViewBag.Clients), as intClient is a ViewBag property, and I cant use ViewBag.intClient

Comment: That's a great idea however I would ask (and a genuine question not a criticism) Don't you then run the risk of bloating your view model with lots of select lists. E.g if your model has say 20 properties each of which gets their info from a select list, you then have 20 select lists inside your model? What if those same 20 select lists (or more/less) are needed elsewhere don't you then risk bloating all your models, I mean if all you do is say display the model on a form (for read/only) that model is then always carrying that overhead ?

Answer (score 9):

Personally...I create a List and do this.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    list.Add(new SelectListItem(){Text = "One", Value="One"});
    list.Add(new SelectListItem(){Text = "Two", Value="Two"});
    list.Add(new SelectListItem(){Text = "Three", Value="Three"});
    list.Add(new SelectListItem(){Text = "Four", Value="Four"});

    ViewBag.Clients = list;

    return View();
}
```

and then in your view...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SomePropertyOnModel, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Clients);
```

Notice the cast on the Viewbag item.  The cast is required because the viewbag has no idea what the object is for `Viewbag.Client`.  So the cast there is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.intClient, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "ClientId", "ClientName"), string.Empty);
```

The ClientId is the value of the dropdown option.

The ClientName is the text of the dropdown option.

The `string.Empty` at the end adds a blank entry to the dropdown.

Comment: I am using ViewBag to pass the values, that`s the difficulty here

Comment: How to use the ViewBag values to fill a dropdownlistfor?

Comment: Works perfect with IEnumerable<model> ... I pass the values using ViewBag and works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a good reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx