# MVC3 Razor Combo box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can somebody tell me how to create a combo box using mvc3/razor, if it's supported and/or a possible work around?  Thx!

Comment: Do you mean a drop-down list, or a multi-select list ?

Comment: In Windows, a Combo box can allow you to enter text into it.  That's not supported in HTML.  But otherwise, sure. `@Html.DropDownListFor`

Comment: Yep, that just answered my question...looking for text box to enter text as well as select from a list.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to use is a `DropDownList` and I would point you to Darin's response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377402/difficulty-using-viewbag-and-dropdownlistfor/5388297#5388297) for a concise example of how to implement `DropDownListFor`.