# How do I make an editor for a table of true/false values that was generated with a ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, editor, viewmodel

I have an attendance table that displays how I want it to display but one cannot edit any information on the table as of yet.

As far as design, I would like an Administrator to be able to log in, view the table, and (if a piece of attendance data needs changed from "present" to "absent" (or, actually, "true" to false" within the actual database) click on the word "present" or "absent" to toggle the data to the opposite value.

Is this a good design idea for this type of table?  Would it be a much wiser decision to go with dropdowns so every piece of data could be edited and then have a 'submit changes' button and all changes are submitted once (as opposed to querying the entire table after every edit)?

What is the best way to make a page created with this ViewModel editable?

I assume I would edit the ViewModel's Model and after I pass the edited ViewModel back to the controller in the Post action I would bind all of the new data to the appropriate database data.  However, due to the difficulty I had setting up this ViewModel (I had a lot of help from another post here on stackoverflow), I am not sure how I would rebind all of the updated information.

Any tips in the right direction would be helpful.

Below is all of the associated information:

The actual classroom class, or Course:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AttendanceDate { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; } // allows Students to be enrolled in a Course
    etc. . .
}
```

My Students:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; } // allows Student to be enrolled in a Course
    etc. . .
}
```

The entity that ties the Students to the Courses:

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Attendance data:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int AttendanceID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int AttendanceDay { get; set; }  // used to set how many days people are supposed to attend this Course (each course has a different length, some are 10 day courses, some are 3, etc.)
    public bool Present { get; set; }  // absent or present (set to absent by default)
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class AttendanceReportViewModel
{
    public List<int> AttendanceDays { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }

    public string IsPresent(Student student, int attendanceDay)
    {
        return Attendances.Single(a => a.StudentID == student.StudentID && a.AttendanceDay == attendanceDay).Present ? "present" : "absent";
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Attendance Day</th>
            @foreach (var attendanceDay in Model.AttendanceDays)
            {
                <th>@attendanceDay</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@student.LastName</td>
                @foreach (var attendanceDay in Model.AttendanceDays)
                {
                    <td>@Model.IsPresent(student, attendanceDay)</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which yields a table that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is the best way to make a page created with this ViewModel editable?*->

I would prefer a dropdown list (Combo box) with 2 items to select "Present" and "Absent".

Second is to change the color of option "Absent" to red so that it is prominently seen.

You need to do some work with @Html.DropDownListFor() to get it right or use raw html  and  tags. [Dropdown example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388297/1063250)

Finally to post the attendance sheet back to server we need to create a form on the view side that would post the attendance back to the server and then server would update the attendance and return the view.

If the user is a non admin user then the view rendered should not be editable.

The model that can be post back to change the attendance or record a new attendance:

```
public class AttendanceItem
{
    public int AttendanceId {get; set;}
    public int Day {get; set;}
    public int StudentId {get; set;}
    public bool Present { get; set; }
}
```

Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AttendanceView(List<AttendanceItem> AttendanceSheet, int courseId)
{
     //Update the database with AttendanceSheet for course ID.....
     return RedirectToAction("AttendanceView", new { id = courseId });  
}
```