# Populate DropDownList using MVC 4 & Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing MVC4 & Entity Framework Application.I wanted to populate DropDownList,I wanted to bind Category List to Dodropdown list

IRepository Code

```
IList<Category> GetCategory();
```

Repository

```
public IList<Category> GetCategory()
    {
        return (from c in context.Categories
                select c).ToList();

    }
```

Controller

```
  public IList<Category> GetCategory()
    {
        return icategoryRepository.GetCategory();
    }
```

After that I stucked here.How do i bind data to Dropdownlist ?

My View Code here

```
<label for="ProductType">Product Type</label>
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductType,new List<SelectListItem>)
```

My Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult AddProduct()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: you can passed a selectlist through a viewbag/model in controller

Comment: @MillerKoijam how to get data to controller ? using List item ?

Comment: ViewBag.ListOfCategories  = new SelectList(GetCategory(), "Id", "CategoryName");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using ViewBag?

View

```
<label for="ProductType">Product Type</label>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductType,ViewBag.ListOfCategories)
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    ViewBag.ListOfCategories = GetCategory();
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IdCategory, ViewBag.Categories)
```

But I would recommend you to avoid ViewBag/ViewData and profit from your viewmodel:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct()
{
    var model = new TestModel();

//This is just a example, but I advise you to turn your IList in a SelectListItem, for view is more easy to work. Your List Categories will be like this hardcoded:

model.ListCategories= new SelectList(new[]
{
    new { Value = "1", Text = "Category 1" },
    new { Value = "2", Text = "Category 2" },
    new { Value = "3", Text = "Category 3" },
}, "Value", "Text");

return View(model);
```

}

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IdCategory, Model.ListCategories)
```

I hope I have helped

Comment: That's a great idea however I would ask (and a genuine question not a criticism) Don't you then run the risk of bloating your view model with lots of select lists. E.g if your model has say 20 properties each of which gets their info from a select list, you then have 20 select lists inside your model? What if those same 20 select lists (or more/less) are needed elsewhere don't you then risk bloating all your models, I mean if all you do is say display the model on a form (for read/only) that model is then always carrying that overhead ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ViewBag` (as some have suggested in other answers/comments) to get data from your controller to view is generally seen as a code smell.

Your `ViewModel` should ideally contain all of the data you need for your view. So use your controller to populate this data on a property of your ViewModel:

```
SelectList ProductTypes { get; set; }
```

Then bind your dropdown to this value

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductType, Model.ProductTypes)
```

You can find this same answer given on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388297/213902).

Comment: I personally avoid ViewBag because the view will not Strong-Typed

Answer (score 0):

Very simple Code step by step
1) In Entity Framework Class

```
var productsList = (from product in dbContext.Products
                     select new ProductDTO
                     {
                       ProductId = product.ProductId,
                       ProductName = product.ProductName,
                       }).ToList();
```

2) In Controller

```
ViewBag.productsList = new EntityFrameWorkClass().GetBusinessSubCategoriesListForDD();
```

3) In View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Product_ProductId", new SelectList(ViewBag.productsList , "ProductId", "ProductName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

OR

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Product_ProductId, new SelectList(ViewBag.productsList , "ProductId", "ProductName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```