# How to Fill Drop Down List using Model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

```
Function GetStateName() As List(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim ListRoomMaster As List(Of MiscMaster) = New List(Of MiscMaster)
    Dim rm As New MiscMaster
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim sSql = "Select * From dropdown"

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sSql, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim rst As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rst.Read
            rm.m_ddlId = rst!id
            rm.ddlValue = rst!name
            ListRoomMaster.Add(rm)
        Loop
    End Using
    Dim Listxyz = (
        From p In Enumerable.Range(0, 20)
        Select New SelectListItem With {.Text = p.ToString(), .Value = p.ToString()})
Return Listxyz.ToList()
End Function
```

This is the code for GetStateName() Which I am calling from controller Before Viewing This Displays The Drop Down List With 0 to 19 numbers I know I have Miss Something But Don't Know Where to change as most of code are for Linq

This Is Controller Code

```
    Function Index() As ActionResult

        objMisc.StateValue = objMisc.GetStateName()
        'objMisc.StateValue = obj
        Return View(objMisc)
    End Function
```

What I Exactly Want Is Fetching data from DataBase using query 
DataBase Have field like follow
id   | Value
1    | xyz
2    | abx
3    | kvd

I want to populate drop down List As xyz,abx,kvd
And when abx is selected I want to store 2 in database

Comment: have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861635/mvc-best-way-to-populate-html-dropdownlist/25861739#25861739

Comment: Please revise. It's not clear what your question is or the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MVC then you can also get the Data directly in the Razor View from your Model. Because you are doing a SQL Query manually which isnt the puropse of MVC.

Your should return the Model and then you can simply do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.column, Model.dropdown)
```

Comment: And How to get the selected data while using this and I have a little problem that my showing value is different then the storing value 
For Eg. Id= 1 Name = xyz . I would like to show xyz and when xyz is selected I would like to store 1

Comment: I dont know what exactly you mean maybe you should exactly describe the Problem in your Question then I will take a look again. But I suggest you reading a tutorial on MVC and what the purpose of MVC is. Here is a good start http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I find most of tutorial of Linq that what I describe and its hart to interpret from linq to sqlQuery

Comment: I have added more Description about what I exactly needed now If u can suggest me some solutions

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a couple of models:

```
 public NameCode(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Code = name;
        }

public NameCodeCollection(IEnumerable<NameCodeItem> list) : base(list)
        {
        }
```

In razor:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.modelid, new SelectList(Model.modeltext, "Name", "Code"))
```

Use the namecodecollection to feed your dropdown list & read from it.

Comment: How to get the selected value