# Cannot Save record to DB to to SelectListItem Error - Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a strongly typed view using visual studio and have added some dropdownlists for the user to select an option from a connected database table column but these dropdownlists seem to cause some issues. I keep getting the errors below and I am not sure why. These drop downs should be saving the options as a string to corresponding item record. Not sure why it is looking for a key named AssignedTo. Any suggestions? All help is much appreciated.

Error Message:

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'AssignedTo'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 34:         </div>
Line 35:         <div class="editor-field">
Line 36:             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssignedTo, (SelectList)ViewBag.AssignedToList)
Line 37:             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedTo)
Line 38:         </div>
```

Here is my strongly typed Create View:

```
@model ApIssues.Models.AP_Tasks

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Issue</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedTo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssignedTo, (SelectList)ViewBag.AssignedToList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedTo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CC)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CC, (SelectList)ViewBag.CcToList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CC)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Whse)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Whse, (SelectList)ViewBag.WarehouseList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Whse)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PO)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PO)

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FreightNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FreightNo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VendName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReqCompDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReqCompDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReqCompDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaskType)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaskType)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaskType)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

namespace ApIssues.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AP_Tasks
    {
        [Required]
        public int TaskID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Task Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TaskDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Task Type")]
        public string TaskType { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Assigned By")]
        public string AssignedBy { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Assigned To")]
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "CC")]
        public string CC { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Warehouse")]
        public string Whse { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "PO #")]
        public string PO { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Freight #")]
        public string FreightNo { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Vendor Name")]
        public string VendName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Req. Complete Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReqCompDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Completion Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CompDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Notes Summary")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Invoice Date")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> InvDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company Number")]
        public Nullable<int> CoNo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Note Count")]
        public Nullable<int> NoteCnt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Action:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //TODO: Add drop down lists
        //TODO: Change the Cono in Query1
        var nxtDb = new nxtSQLEntities();
        var whses = from w in nxtDb.icsds select w.whse;

        var warehouseList = new SelectList(whses);
            ViewBag.WarehouseList =

 warehouseList;
    var userDb = new PDDAEntities1();
    var query1 = from u in userDb.Users where u.Cono == 1 select new {u.UserName, u.FirstName, u.LastName};
    var query2 = from gm in userDb.GroupMembers
        join ug in userDb.UserGroups on gm.GroupID equals ug.GroupID
        join u in userDb.Users on gm.UserName equals u.UserName
        where ug.GroupName == "AP Department" || ug.GroupName == "MIS"
        orderby new {u.LastName, u.FirstName}
        select new {UserName = u.UserName, FirstName = u.FirstName, LastName = u.LastName};
        var query3 = query1.Concat(query2);

    var results = new List<string>{};
    results.AddRange(query3.Select(entry => entry.UserName));

    ViewBag.AssignedToList = new SelectList(results);
    ViewBag.CcToList = new SelectList(results);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AP_Tasks task)
{

    // Save an task to the database
    var db = new Accounting_AaronTestEntities();
    try
    {
        db.AP_Tasks.Add(task);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssignedTo,
                    new SelectList(ViewBag.AssignedToList, "Id", "AssignedTo"), "---Select Assigner---", new { ID = "ddlAssigned" })
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try variants of the top two answers here:

[Having difficulty using an ASP.NET MVC ViewBag and DropDownListfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377402/having-difficulty-using-an-asp-net-mvc-viewbag-and-dropdownlistfor)